# Jquery works fine in fire bug but not the page

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have a web page which has an upload box and uploads an image. the jquery is as follows. User browses a file and clicks a button named btn_AddImage and the file is uploaded. The problem is that the code only works when I put breakpoint on "if (xhr.readyState == 4)" in firebug and the "btn_ShowImage" element is shown. If i do not put the break point, the file would be uploaded but the page still alerts error and the "btn_ShowImage" element would be still hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_AddImage').live('click', AjaxFileUpload);
});
function AjaxFileUpload() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("image_Upload");
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("files", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'ImageFileUploader.ashx');
    xhr.send(fd);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        $('#btn_ShowImage').show();
    }
    else {
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

thanks for your responses. I have corrected my code and it is working. The corrected code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_AddImage').live('click', AjaxFileUpload);

});

function AjaxFileUpload() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("image_Upload");
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("files", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'ImageFileUploader.ashx');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             $('#btn_ShowImage').show();
        }
        else if (uploadResult == 'success')
            alert('error');
    };
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: xhr.send is asynchronous - put the show call in the success callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "A" in "AJAX" stands for "asynchronous" :)

Meaning: You're setting up the XHR object and inspecting its "readyState" property synchronously - even before the ajax call *really* went out. You should rather set up and fire the AJAX request and listen for the "readyStateChange" event - this might get called multiple times until the request is fully completed.

Another question that comes to mind immediately: You're using jQuery for event binding on the button - why do you fiddle around with XHR yourself and not simply also use jQuery for AJAX?

Comment: Well I do not know how to send my file using ajax and jquery and without using plugins. Could you help me to rewrite the above code using jquery.ajax?

Comment: You must fall back to XHR in order to make use of most elements of the File API.